# Reading Safari cookies in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mobile-safari

is it possible to read the cookies of Safari in an own iPhone App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To allow this would fly in the face of the stringent security on the platform.